# Dask multi-stage resource setup causes Failed to Serialize Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

Using the exact code from Dask's documentation at
https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/examples.html

In case the page changes, this is the code:

```
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
from distributed import Client
from dask import delayed

cluster = SLURMCluster(memory='8g',
                       processes=1,
                       cores=2,
                       extra=['--resources ssdGB=200,GPU=2'])

cluster.scale(2)
client = Client(cluster)

def step_1_w_single_GPU(data):
    return "Step 1 done for: %s" % data


def step_2_w_local_IO(data):
    return "Step 2 done for: %s" % data


stage_1 = [delayed(step_1_w_single_GPU)(i) for i in range(10)]
stage_2 = [delayed(step_2_w_local_IO)(s2) for s2 in stage_1]

result_stage_2 = client.compute(stage_2,
                                resources={tuple(stage_1): {'GPU': 1},
                                           tuple(stage_2): {'ssdGB': 100}})
```

This results in an error of such:

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 76, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 38, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 294, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 300, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 297, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 229, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 291, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'Delayed' object
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - can not serialize 'Delayed' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 33, in _to_frames
    return list(protocol.dumps(msg, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 76, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 38, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 294, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 300, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 297, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 229, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 291, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'Delayed' object
distributed.batched - ERROR - Error in batched write
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/batched.py", line 94, in _background_send
    nbytes = yield self.comm.write(
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 250, in write
    frames = await to_frames(
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 50, in to_frames
    return _to_frames()
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 33, in _to_frames
    return list(protocol.dumps(msg, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 76, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/eagleseven/pyenv/e7cloudv0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 38, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 294, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 300, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 297, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 229, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 291, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'Delayed' object
```

Python verion: 3.8.10
dask: 2022.2.0
dask-jobqueue: 0.7.3
The problem is self-evident. Setup is just like in the documentation. There is nothing more I can explain, but stackoverflow is saying my details-to-code is too low, so I need to write more stuff to allow this question to be posted.

Comment: this seems like it might be a bug in the documentation. you could probably post this directly to the [dask-jobqueue issues board](https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues). I don't know what the right way to do this is, but I'm sure someone there would, and the documentation certainly shouldn't be leading you astray. I don't see anything in the [dask.distributed API docs](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.compute) indicating you can provide a dictionary with futures/delayed as keys and normal resources specs as values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by @Michael Delgado in the comments, this appears to be a problem with the documentation (raised [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/pull/554)). Resources are a dictionary with each key being name of a resource and value representing the amount used by a task.

In an answer to a related question, Matt Rocklin, the initial commit author, mentions that this feature (specifying task-level resources) is frequently requested, but not available as of now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63310721/10693596

One possibility is to use `annotation` for specific components of the graph, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69461969/10693596).

Comment: The tier-ed annotation would be adequate approach.